# What is causing a Java certificate confirmation for javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com to show?

Tags: windows, java, certificate, popups

For the last 3 days I occasionally get this window in front of me:

> **Do you want to Continue?**
>
> The web site's certificate has been verified.
>
> Website: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com:443
>
> Note: The certificate is valid and has been used to verify the identity of this website.

[image]

This popup message is not related to my Pale Moon browser. I deactivated Java plugins in any browser. This is some background service that connects to a server not any user made query.

I think it's related to installing the Java SE development Kit. Earlier, when I only had the Java runtime environment without the development kit, I did not get asked this question at all.

I guess it is a certificate confirmation for a Java update server query.
But it bugs me, that this window does not explain itself what it's for.
Also it's in always on top mode and distracts me while doing something else.
Can somebody confirm my guess?

The screenshot also contains my Pale Moon plugin settings in the background to indicate that I haven't activated any Java web plugins.

(Windows 7 x64 with Java 8 JRE and JDK installed.)

Comment: Edit is fine gronostaj, because I could not use the su.com embedding yet.

Comment: Yes;  This is a confirmation window generated by the website you navigated to.  As for the reason its being displayed that would be your Java security settings.

Comment: I did not navigate to a site in a java context.

Comment: Something is causing communication with `javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com` and due to the way your Java security settings are configured you are being asked to trust the certificate.

Comment: Yes, and I want to know if this is typical for the default settings. And if this is triggered because of oracles updater.

Comment: Is it typical to be asked to trust a certificate signed by what I assume is a CA, without information on the certificate your being asked to trust, that is difficult to answer.  Firefox does not use the system's certificate store.  This problem might be unique to Palefox, with the current provided information, its difficult to answer the question and not possible to even attempt to explain the behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27340/discussion-between-bryan-shadow-and-ramhound).

Comment: I guess that Task Manger should show some process while the dialog is stopping that process from continuing?

Comment: What is wrong with enabling "Always trust ..." on the dialog? Or do you not trust Oracle?

Comment: I actually checked always trust then. As said in the answer, normally that gets approved automatically without interaction as the cert is in jre's trust store. Because of this unusualness I thought to ask if this is actually legit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have checked it, this certificate confirmation is triggered by the Java Auto Updater and goes to the update server by Oracle.

The update trigger is a scheduled task in Windows that is created by the Java installer.
Before having the JDK installed this certificate would have been silently approved, an update found and a Windows balloon message generated that a new version of Java is available.